# CGAffineTransform.identity in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, swift2

**Swift 3.0**

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
transform = transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
transform = transform.translatedBy(x: translation.x/scale, y: translation.y/scale)
```

I tried this one

```
let transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
let translateValue  = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,translation.x / scale , translation.y / scale)
```

but not getting required result, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API like Core Graphics that have been refined for Swift you can toggle over to the Objective-C documentation and it will find the corresponding symbol. These were the same symbols that Core Graphics used in Swift 2.x before the API was refined.

If you do this for [`scaledBy(x:y:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455882-scaledby?language=swift)

[image: Swift documentation]

you'll see that the corresponding symbol is [CGAffineTransformScale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455882-cgaffinetransformscale?language=objc) (note that it's ...`Scale` and not ...`MakeScale`).

[image: Objective-C documentation]

I don't have a Xcode with Swift 2.x readily available, but your Swift 2.3 code would looks something like this:

```
var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale)
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, translation.x / scale, translation.y / scale)
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
```

does not scale your `transform`.  So you simply made a small mistake in the conversion.

So, as the identity is the default, this should work:

```
let transform      = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
let translateValue = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, translation.x / scale , translation.y / scale)
```